# Why this program is giving a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
char *p = "hello world!";
p[0] = 'H';
printf("%s",p);
getch();
}
```

I am new to C, can u guys tell me why is this program giving a segmentation fault?

Comment: Pointers declared this way point to a non-changeable part of memory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string Better duplicate target

Comment: You are modifying a string literal which is *undefined* in C. You could use an array instead: `char p[]="hello world!";` which will allow you to modify it. [More on this here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Because you try to set `p[0]` to `'H'`. *p points to a string literal, which is stored in read-only memory.

Comment: String literals are not necessarily stored in read-only memory. It's simply undefined behaviour to modify them.